# Undefined offset error in array when count show the number of element inside

Tags: php, arrays

As stated in the title, I encounter a strange problem for the following code.

```
 for($i=0; $i < count($maindata) ; $i++){
     $currentId = $maindata[$i]['SubmissionId'];                            
     $output = array_filter($subdata, function ($value) use ($currentId) 
            { return $subdata['ParentId'] == $currentId; });

     echo 'total sub data '.count($output); //output 86

     for($j=0; $j < count($output) ; $j++){
         echo $output[$j]['SubmissionId'];  //Undefined offset Error                       
     }
}
```

As you can see, I loop through an array. Inside the loop I filter out another array to get the associate data.

And then I echo the count of the filter `array` and echo the data with another loop. The code was fine for first item and it show data but starting from the second item, it show

> Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in myfile on line 79

inside the second loop but the **count still showing correct answer** also. line 79 is `echo $output[$j]['SubmissionId'];  //Undefined offset Error`   .

Please help me to figure out what is the problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: to remove your error you need to do  `if(isset($output[$j]['SubmissionId'])){echo $output[$j]['SubmissionId'];}`. More you have to print `$output` before second iteration and show us the data. May be some correction required

Comment: please put the full error message. Add a sample of the $output array

Comment: That is hardly what one would call a full error trace. Usually they are accomopanied by a line nunber too. For all we know the error might not even be on the line that you think it is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution:-

Inside second iteration use this:-

```
if(isset($output[$j]['SubmissionId'])){echo $output[$j]['SubmissionId'];}
```

Explanation:-

`$output` is a  filtered sub-array and due to filtration it's quite possible that some indexes are missing

when you did `for($j=0; $j < count($output) ; $j++){` and if `count($output)` is `86` means loop will go for `0-85` (in sequential order)

Now if `$output` has missed index `3` (for example) then the code `$output[$j]['SubmissionId']` will give error

So check that using above code and problem is solved.

***2nd opinion:-***

you can do like below:-

```
$output = array_values($output);
echo 'total sub data '.count($output); //output 86

for($j=0; $j < count($output) ; $j++){
 echo $output[$j]['SubmissionId'];
}
```

*Note:- this approach will re-index your array and if some-where you are going to use original indexes then this code will lead you to problems.*

***3rd option(better than 2nd one)***

Since `foreach()` take care of indexes so instead of `for()` loop use `foreach`.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In first place , i think that "foreach" loop instead of "for" will be more clear and a better practice for what you need.

http://php.net/manual/fr/control-structures.foreach.php

In a second time, do you try to make a var_dump instead of echo to see what structure you have into your array?

```
for($i=0; $i < count($maindata) ; $i++){
 $currentId = $maindata[$i]['SubmissionId'];                            
 $output = array_filter($subdata, function ($value) use ($currentId) 
        { return $subdata['ParentId'] == $currentId; });

 var_dump($output);exit();

 .....
```

Maybe you don't have  SubmissionId sub-index inside.

Comment: Yes. foreach was my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem by printing out the array as @Anant mention. At first I thought $output arrary's index will be starting from zero as normal array. But, since I got this from array_filter, the index starting from the end of last filtered array.

So I change the second loop to foreach and problem solved now.

Thank you all!!!